# Removing root node in json in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json data stored in a variable.

**Json Data:**

```
{ "XYZ": { "abc":[{....}] } }
```

From above JSON Data, I should not have XYZ node. I need JSON Data as

```
{ "abc":[{....}] }
```

How can I remove using Python?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You want to look up the dictionary via it's key ("XYZ") and assign it to a new variable:

`data = request_data.get("XYZ")`

this will return `None` if there is no "XYZ" key, but if you know the "XYZ" key is always going to be there you can lookup like so:

`data = requests_data["XYZ"]`